# Should answers be multithreaded by default?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

Often in StackOverflow, you find a C# or Java question that is not specifically asking for multi-threaded code, but many answers and comments focus on providing a thread safe solution.  Should this be encouraged?  Should I be writing sigle or multi threaded code in answers by default?

Comment: If the likes of Donald Knuth have problems with Multi-threaded code; then chances are good your average Stack Overflow user will. Just sayin'.

Comment: Just curious, how is this blatantly offensive?  I'll be happy to delete if someone will fill me in.

Comment: ah, the joys of multi-threading....

Answer (score 5):

#### Hell. No.

Imagine the scenario: Fairly new to the language user wants a bit of help doing something. They either find a question here, or ask their own. They find some crazy-threaded example, when they're still not really sure what threads are! SO is for everybody, not just the elite. `How do I do X (with multithreading)` is a totally legitimate, but entirely seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

**IMO**

I write single threaded code by default, both when programming and when answering questions.  It's basic adherence to the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it), and it makes things less confusing for beginners.

I don't mind getting multi-threaded answers myself, it's sort of a value added thing.